# VBA selenium selecting an element with ext:qtip attribute

Tags: vba, selenium, select, element

I'm trying to select and element which has a specific atribute.

```html
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-7 x-unselectable" unselectable="on" ext:qtip="Final" style="background:none;with=100%;background-image:url(/images/18_status_final.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" id="flgstatus_id">&nbsp;</div>
```

It's : "ext:qtip='Final'.

I'm trying to select it with

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(.,'Final')]").Click
```

It returns: element not found.

However i am able to select it using

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[8]/div").Click
```

My goal is to check if an element has 'Final' and select it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: FindElementByCss("[ext\:qtip=Final]")  something like that might work but may throw an error

Comment: Nice, it works, but what if there are multiple CSS with "Final", how to select all of them?

Comment: Solved it with bot.FindElementsByCss("[ext\:qtip=Final]").Item(2).Click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindElementByCss("[ext\:qtip=Final]")`

to select it

`bot.FindElementsByCss("[ext\:qtip=Final]").Item(2).Click`

to choose an item.